# Is it possible to append 2 rich text strings?

Tags: java, html, apache-poi

I need to append to 2 HSSFRichTextStrings in Java with Apache POI.  How can I do this?
What I'm exactly doing is I'm getting the rich text string already present in a cell and I'm trying to append an additional rich text string to it and write it back to the cell.
Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Looking at the javadoc it does not seem to be possible. You can alway create a new HSSFRichTextStrings with the concatenated string and re-apply the formatting...

Comment: But I cant say for sure wat formatting was applied to the rich text string already present in a cell. How can do it then? Is it possible to get the font of a rich text string?

Comment: I don't know how HSSFRichTextStrings work, I just looked at the javadoc. It has methods to read and write formatting character by character - so I would have thought you can use them... (http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRichTextString.html#applyFont%28int,%20int,%20short%29) and (http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRichTextString.html#getFontAtIndex%28int%29)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to append two `HSSFRichTextStrings`, but you will have to do most of the work yourself.  You will need to take advantage of the following methods in `HSSFRichTextString`:

- [numFormattingRuns()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRichTextString.html#numFormattingRuns%28%29) - Returns the number of formatting runs in the `HSFFRichTextString`.
- [getFontOfFormattingRun(int)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRichTextString.html#getFontOfFormattingRun%28int%29) - Returns the `short` font index present at the specified position in the string
- [applyFont(int, int, short)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRichTextString.html#applyFont%28int,%20int,%20short%29) - Applies the font referred to by the `short` font index between the given start index (inclusive) and end index (exclusive).

First, create a little class to store formatting run stats:

```
public class FormattingRun {
    private int beginIdx;
    private int length;
    private short fontIdx;
    public FormattingRun(int beginIdx, int length, short fontIdx) {
        this.beginIdx = beginIdx;
        this.length = length;
        this.fontIdx = fontIdx;
    }
    public int getBegin() { return beginIdx; }
    public int getLength() { return length; }
    public short getFontIndex { return fontIdx; }
}
```

Next, gather all of the formatting run statistics for each of the two strings.  You'll have to walk the strings yourself to determine how long each formatting run lasts.

```
List<FormattingRun> formattingRuns = new ArrayList<FormattingRun>();
int numFormattingRuns = richTextString.numFormattingRuns();
for (int fmtIdx = 0; fmtIdx < numFormattingRuns; fmtIdx)
{
    int begin = richTextString.getIndexOfFormattingRun(fmtIdx);
    short fontIndex = richTextString.getFontOfFormattingRun(fmtIdx);

    // Walk the string to determine the length of the formatting run.
    int length = 0;
    for (int j = begin; j < richTextString.length(); j++)
    {
        short currFontIndex = richTextString.getFontAtIndex(j);
        if (currFontIndex == fontIndex)
            length++;
        else
            break;
    }
    formattingRuns.add(new FormattingRun(begin, length, fontIndex));
}
```

Next, concatenate the two `String` values yourself and create the result `HSSFRichTextString`.

```
HSSFRichTextString result = new HSSFRichTextString(
     richTextString1.getString() + richTextString2.getString());
```

Last, apply both sets of formatting runs, with the second set of runs being offset by the first string's length.

```
for (FormattingRun run1 : formattingRuns1)
{
    int begin = run1.getBegin();
    int end = begin + run1.getLength();
    short fontIdx = run1.getFontIndex();
    result.applyFont(begin, end, fontIdx);
}
for (FormattingRun run2 : formattingRuns2)
{
    // offset by string length 1
    int begin = run2.getBegin() + richTextString1.length();
    int end = begin + run2.getLength();
    short fontIdx = run2.getFontIndex();
    result.applyFont(begin, end, fontIdx);
}
```

That should do it for concatenating `HSSFRichTextStrings`.

If you ever want to concatenate `XSSFRichTextStrings`, found in .xlsx files, the process is very similar.  One difference is that `XSSFRichTextString#getFontOfFormattingRun` will return an `XSSFFont` instead of a `short` font index.  That's okay, because calling `applyFont` on an `XSSFRichTextString` takes an `XSSFFont` anyway.  Another difference is that `getFontOfFormattingRun` may throw a `NullPointerException` if there is no font applied for the formatting run, which occurs when there is no different font applied than the font that is already there for the `CellStyle` for the entire `Cell`.

Comment: How do you get around the NullPointerException for XSSFRichTextStrings?

Comment: @user1007895 Catch the `NullPointerException` thrown by `getFontOfFormattingRun`; that is the case where there is no formatting run at that index.  Don't create a `FormattingRun` for that gap where there is no font applied.  Then you won't call `applyFont` for the corresponding gap in the new `XSSFRichTextString`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using XSSFRichTextStrings, you can't directly concatenate two RichTextString.

However, you can indirectly do so by finding the text value of the second RichTextString and then using the append method to append that string value with an applied font (RichText in essence).

```
XSSFRichTextString rt1 = new XSSFRichTextString("Apache POI is");
rt1.applyFont(plainArial);
XSSFRichTextString rt2 = new XSSFRichTextString(" great!");
rt2.applyFont(boldArial);
String text = rt2.getString();

cell1.setCellValue(rt1.append(text, boldArial));
```

Source:

[enter link description here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRichTextString.html)