# Is it possible to concatenate 2 HSSFRichTextString?

Tags: java, html, apache, apache-poi

Hey im trying to concatenate 2 HSSFRichTextStrings in apache poi. 
I have some richText String already inputted in a cell. I need to concatenate that richText String with certain other richText String and put it back in the same cell?
Please tell tell me how to do this? 
Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to append 2 rich text strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699151/is-it-possible-to-append-2-rich-text-strings)

Answer (score 0):

May be it works

```
HSSFRichTextString s = row.getCell(1).getRichStringCellValue();
HSSFRichTextString s2 = row.getCell(2).getRichStringCellValue();
HSSFRichTextString s3 = new HSSFRichTextString(s.getString() + s2.getString());
row.getCell(1).setCellValue(s3);
```