# Convert a POI RichTextString to HTML or RTF

Tags: java, apache-poi, rtf, import-from-excel

I have an application where I am reading in an Excel file using Apache POI.
Some of the cells may have formatting (bullets, underline etc). What I want to do is then display the contents of the Cell in a HTML page - keeping the format.

I have seen answers that can convert RTF strings to HTML - so that I can do.

I can see a lot of answers going from RTF to POI RichTextString - but I want to go the other way - i.e., convert the value stored in the Cell represented by RichTextString into an actual RTF string (or HTML).

Has anyone done this?

Comment: Apache POI has converters from Excel to HTML, eg the [ToHTML Example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/html/ToHtml.java) - did you try that?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - that has led me to my solution

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Gagravarr who pointed me to the ToHTML example.

The examples only did cell wide markup - they did not take into account formatting with in a cell.

But building on solutions such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338037/apache-poi-read-and-store-rich-text-content-in-db - I was able to go through the formatting runs in a cell.

Calling formatCell() will convert the cell to html.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellFormat;
import org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellFormatResult;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import static org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;

/**
 *
 * @author Anthony Symons <anthony.symons@linxmgt.com>
 */
public class RichTextStringToHtml {

    private final HSSFWorkbook wb;
    private final HSSFPalette colors;
    private StringBuilder sb;
    private Cell cell;
    private Sheet sheet;

    private static final Map<Short, String> ALIGN = mapFor(ALIGN_LEFT, "left",
            ALIGN_CENTER, "center", ALIGN_RIGHT, "right", ALIGN_FILL, "left",
            ALIGN_JUSTIFY, "left", ALIGN_CENTER_SELECTION, "center");
    private static final Map<Short, String> VERTICAL_ALIGN = mapFor(
            VERTICAL_BOTTOM, "bottom", VERTICAL_CENTER, "middle", VERTICAL_TOP,
            "top");
    private static final Map<Short, String> BORDER = mapFor(BORDER_DASH_DOT,
            "dashed 1pt", BORDER_DASH_DOT_DOT, "dashed 1pt", BORDER_DASHED,
            "dashed 1pt", BORDER_DOTTED, "dotted 1pt", BORDER_DOUBLE,
            "double 3pt", BORDER_HAIR, "solid 1px", BORDER_MEDIUM, "solid 2pt",
            BORDER_MEDIUM_DASH_DOT, "dashed 2pt", BORDER_MEDIUM_DASH_DOT_DOT,
            "dashed 2pt", BORDER_MEDIUM_DASHED, "dashed 2pt", BORDER_NONE,
            "none", BORDER_SLANTED_DASH_DOT, "dashed 2pt", BORDER_THICK,
            "solid 3pt", BORDER_THIN, "dashed 1pt");
    private static final HSSFColor HSSF_AUTO = new HSSFColor.AUTOMATIC();

    public RichTextStringToHtml(Cell c, StringBuilder sb) {
        cell = c;
        sheet = cell.getSheet();
        wb = (HSSFWorkbook) sheet.getWorkbook();
        colors = wb.getCustomPalette();
        this.sb = sb;
    }

    private static <K, V> Map<K, V> mapFor(Object... mapping) {
        Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mapping.length; i += 2) {
            map.put((K) mapping[i], (V) mapping[i + 1]);
        }
        return map;
    }

    public void colorStyles(CellStyle style) {
        HSSFCellStyle cs = (HSSFCellStyle) style;

        styleColor("background-color", cs.getFillForegroundColor());
        styleColor("color", cs.getFont(wb).getColor());

    }

    private void styleColor(String attr, short index) {
        HSSFColor color = colors.getColor(index);
        if (index == HSSF_AUTO.getIndex() || color == null) {
        } else {
            short[] rgb = color.getTriplet();
            sb.append(String.format("  %s: #%02x%02x%02x; /* index = %d */", attr, rgb[0],
                    rgb[1], rgb[2], index));
        }
    }

    private <K> void styleOut(String attr, K key, Map<K, String> mapping) {
        String value = mapping.get(key);
        if (value != null) {
            sb.append("  ").append(attr).append(": ").append(value);

        }
    }

    private void fontStyle(short fontIndex) {
        Font font = wb.getFontAt(fontIndex);
        if (font.getBoldweight() >= HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_NORMAL) {
            sb.append("  font-weight: bold;");
        }
        if (font.getItalic()) {
            sb.append("  font-style: italic;");
        }
        int fontheight = font.getFontHeightInPoints();
        if (fontheight == 9) {
            //fix for stupid ol Windows
            fontheight = 10;
        }
        sb.append("  font-size: ").append(fontheight).append("pt;");
        styleColor("color", font.getColor());

        // Font color is handled with the other colors
    }

    private void getHtmlFromHss(HSSFRichTextString richTextString) {


        //List<FormattingRun> formattingRuns = new ArrayList<FormattingRun>();
        int numFormattingRuns = richTextString.numFormattingRuns();
        String baseString = richTextString.getString();
        CellStyle cs = cell.getCellStyle();
        short csFont = cs.getFontIndex();
        sb.append("<span style=").append('"');
        fontStyle(csFont);
        sb.append('"').append(">");
        if (numFormattingRuns <= 0) {
            // no formatting so just copy in the string
            sb.append(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(baseString));
            sb.append("</span>");

            return;
        }
        int firstIndex = richTextString.getIndexOfFormattingRun(0);
        int currOffset = 0;

        while (currOffset < firstIndex) {
            sb.append(escapeHtml(baseString.charAt(currOffset)));
            currOffset++;
        }
        for (int fmtIdx = 0; fmtIdx < numFormattingRuns; fmtIdx++) {
            int begin = richTextString.getIndexOfFormattingRun(fmtIdx);
            short fontIndex = richTextString.getFontOfFormattingRun(fmtIdx);
            // apply the font at this point
            // Walk the string to determine the length of the formatting run.
            sb.append("</span><span style=").append('"');
            fontStyle(fontIndex);
            sb.append('"').append(">");
            for (int j = begin; j < richTextString.length(); j++) {
                short currFontIndex = richTextString.getFontAtIndex(j);

                if (currFontIndex == fontIndex) {
                    sb.append(escapeHtml(baseString.charAt(currOffset)));
                    currOffset++;
                } else {

                    break;
                }
            }
            //formattingRuns.add(new FormattingRun(begin, length, fontIndex));
        }
        sb.append("</span>");

    }

    public String escapeHtml(char in) {
        switch (in) {
            case '\n':
            case '\r':
                return "<br/>";

        }
        return StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4("" + in);
    }

    public void formatCell() {




        String content = null;
        String attrs = "";
        CellStyle style = null;


        style = cell.getCellStyle();
        attrs = tagStyle(cell, style);
        //Set the value that is rendered for the cell
        //also applies the format
        CellFormat cf = CellFormat.getInstance(
                style.getDataFormatString());
        CellFormatResult result = cf.apply(cell);
        try {
            getHtmlFromHss((HSSFRichTextString) cell.getRichStringCellValue());
        } catch (java.lang.IllegalStateException ex) {
        }




    }

    private String tagStyle(Cell cell, CellStyle style) {
        if (style.getAlignment() == ALIGN_GENERAL) {
            switch (ultimateCellType(cell)) {
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    return "style=\"text-align: left;\"";
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                    return "style=\"text-align: center;\"";
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                default:
                    // "right" is the default
                    break;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    private static int ultimateCellType(Cell c) {
        int type = c.getCellType();
        if (type == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
            type = c.getCachedFormulaResultType();
        }
        return type;
    }


}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. For a simple cell formatted as "£99 ~~£55~~" it retunes a string buffer starting "<span style=" font-weight: bold; ...."

Comment: font.getBoldweight() >= HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_NORMAL
should be
font.getBoldweight() > HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_NORMAL
based on
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font.html#BOLDWEIGHT_NORMAL