How to get the html formatting from Excel Sheet Cells in Java
We are trying to get the html formatting from excel cell(basically the cell text in html format) including bullet points, italics, new lines, highlights, hyperlinks etc.
We are using Apache POI but it does not offer those exact capabilities, Tried Aspose cells as well but throws "Could not find com.aspose:aspose-cells:24.4" error every time even after adding correct repository URL too like following:
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://releases.aspose.com/java/repo/"
    }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

Can someone suggest how can we achieve this requirement for below text in Excel cell:


Does the cell actually contain html markup?

Are you asking how to do it with Aspose?

See the document (https://docs.aspose.com/cells/java/installation/) on how to configure and install Aspose.Cells for Java from maven repository for your reference.

@g00se yes it contains html markup like bold, italics, new lines etc

@aled yes, because even Aspose is giving me errors as mentioned in the question, And we are using Gradle.

Possibly a silly question, but why doesn't it come out when you get the raw text?

Apache POI will happily give you the formatting information back of a "rich text" cell, see eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792125/convert-a-poi-richtextstring-to-html-or-rtf


Tried Aspose cells as well but throws "Could not find
com.aspose:aspose-cells:24.4" error every time even after adding
correct repository URL too like following

I tested using a sample Gradle project in eclipse where the target Java version is 21. It works fine and both Aspose.Cells for Java 24.4 and Aspose.Slides for Java 24.4 libraries are added to "Project and External Dependencies" node in eclipse. Here is gradle.build file content in the project for your reference.
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java application project to get you started.
 * For more details on building Java & JVM projects, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/building_java_projects.html in the Gradle documentation.
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()

    // Aspose repository
    maven {
        url "https://releases.aspose.com/java/repo/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit test framework.
    testImplementation libs.junit

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation libs.guava
    implementation("com.aspose:aspose-cells:24.4")
    implementation("com.aspose:aspose-slides:24.4:jdk16")
}

// Apply a specific Java toolchain to ease working on different environments.
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'org.example.App'
}

Now come to your task on "how to get the html formatting from Excel Sheet Cells in Java", there are two ways to accomplish your task.

Aspose.Cells provides Cell.getHtmlString attribute which you may use to get HTML formatted string/text of the cell.
Render Excel worksheet/workbook to HTML file.

I placed a sample file "SampleExcelFile.xlsx" in the app folder. Now I write the following sample code in the main (Java) class to retrieve the HTML of a cell in the worksheet. I also save the workbook to HTML file.
e.g.,
Sample code:
/*
 * This source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task
 */
package org.example;

import com.aspose.cells.Workbook;
import com.aspose.cells.Worksheet;
import com.aspose.cells.Cells;
import com.aspose.cells.Cell;
import com.aspose.cells.SaveFormat;

import java.nio.file.ClosedFileSystemException;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      
        // Open the Excel file
        Workbook workbook = new Workbook("SampleExcelFile.xlsx");
        // Get the first worksheet in the workbook
        Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);
        // Access cell A1
        Cells cells = worksheet.getCells();
        Cell cell = cells.get("A1");
        // Get HTML formatting string of the cell
        String html = cell.getHtmlString();
        
        // Save to HTML file        
        workbook.save("out1.html", SaveFormat.HTML);    
    }
}

Hope, this helps a bit.
